# Slot Machine simultaneous jQuery animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm trying to create Slot Machine effect for lottery.
The target numbers will be already set, so that once the stop button is pressed it should stop on that number.
Everything is working fine for slot 1. But if I add the same code for slot 2 and slot 3 then it's creating the problem.

Below given is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  s1 = 1;
  s2 = 1;
  s3 = 1;
  num1 = 6;
  num2 = 5;
  num3 = 7; //Target for 3 slots
  i = 100; //Top margin for animation

  $('#start').click(function() {
    animateslot(50, 0);
  });

  $("#stop").click(function() {
    stopanimationslot1(50, 0);
  });
});


function animateslot(d = 150, i = 0) {
  i = i + 100;
  $('#slot1').animate({
    marginTop: -i
  }, {
    duration: d,
    complete: function() {
      $("#slot1").append("<h3>Column " + s1 + "</h3>");
      s1++;
      if (s1 > 9) {
        s1 = 1;
      }
      console.log(s1);
      animateslot(d, i);
    }
  });

  //If below given code is added it doesn't work**
  /*
  $('#slot2').animate(
   {
    marginTop: -i
   },
   {
    duration: d,
       complete: function() {
       $("#slot2").append("<h3>Column "+s2+"</h3>");
       s2++;
       if(s2>9){
        s2 = 1;
       }
       console.log("s2="+s2);
        animateslot(d, i);
    }
   }
  );
  */
}

function stopanimationslot1(d = 150, i = 0, num = 1) {
  $('#slot1').stop();
  i = i + 100;
  $('#slot1').animate({
    marginTop: -i
  }, d, function() {
    if (Math.abs(i / 100) == num1) {
      $('#slot1').clearQueue().stop(false, true);
      console.log("finished");
    } else {
      $("#slot1").append("<h3>Column " + s1 + "</h3>");
      s1++;
      if (s1 > 9) {
        s1 = 1;
      }
      stopanimationslot1(d + 50, i, num);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#slot1 h3,
#slot2 h3,
#slot3 h3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 0;
}

#slotmachine {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:(0);" id="start" class="btn btn-default">Start</a><br><br>
<a href="javascript:(0);" id="stop" class="btn btn-default">Stop</a><br><br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="slotmachine">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="slot1">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="slot2">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="slot3">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/sushanttayade123/fqkgvu59/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it's not working as expected lies in `animateslot(d, i);`.

After pressing start:

- Slot 1 completes and calls `animateslot()`
- Slot 2 completes and **also** calls `animateslot()`

On the next "animation cycle", the method will not run once as it did before, but **twice**, which results in the stuttery behaviour. The amount of calls will constantly grow at a factor of two for every cycle.

To fix this, either call `animateSlot()` **once** after all animations have completed or move every slot into it's own function (`animateSlot1()`, `animateSlot2()`, ...).

A word of advice at the end: I wouldn't recommend adding a new node after every spin, as this can cause performance drops.